# can't view S3 Bucket image object from EC2 hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created an IAM role that gives full access to the S3 Bucket and attached it to the EC2 instance. However, I am unable to view the image when I try to view it from the EC2 hosted website. I keep getting a 403 Forbidden code.

Below is the IAM role and the policy attached:
[image: iam role]

It is seen that GetObject is enabled:
[image: getobject]

But the error still persists:
[image: error persists]

Any advice on how to solve this? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using to access the object does not appear to include any security information (`bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/cat1.jpg`). Thus, it is simply an 'anonymous' request to S3, and since the object is private, S3 will deny the request.

The mere fact that the request is being sent from an Amazon EC2 instance that has been assigned an IAM Role is not sufficient to obtain access to the object via an anonymous URL.

To allow a browser to access a private Amazon S3 object, your application should generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). This is a time-limited URL that includes security information that identifies you as the requester and includes a signature that permits access to the private object.

Alternatively, code running on the instance can use an AWS SDK to make an API call to S3 to access the object (eg `GetObject()`). This will succeed because the AWS SDK will use the credentials provided by the IAM Role.